# ggplot - using a vector mask for a raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, rasterizing

I am trying to create a vector mask to a raster. The raster is some color gradient created elswhere. Here I am discussing only the vector mask.

Using the raster and sf packages seems to be an overkill for the simple case. The best way I came up with is to plot the vector object, ggsave it to a raster file, read it back and then overlay it on the original raster.

will be happy to hear any better suggestion.

Anyway, when I write the plot to the the file there is always a small frame around it. It may not be visible when displaying the file on screen but its problematic in my case.
I could remove the frame but I cannot rely on color only and I am not sure that its always the same size. Here is my exampe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(bmp)

pol <- tibble(x = c(1, 3, 5, 4), y = c(3,5, 4, 1))

p <- ggplot(pol) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x,y), fill = "red") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank())

ggsave("pol.bmp", p, dpi = "screen")

bmp <- read.bmp("pol.bmp")
bmp <- melt(bmp, varnames = c("y", "x")) %>%
  mutate(value = as.factor(value))

ggplot(bmp) +
  geom_raster(aes(x,y, fill = value)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

The initial plot

[image: initial plot]

The raterized plot (ignore colors)
[image]

Please advise

Comment: Not sure I see how the question content follows from the title - what raster are you wanting to mask with what polygon?

Comment: Here I talking only about the vector. The raster is a different color raster I created and I want to mask it with this vector. Will rephrase the question

Comment: Without using something like the raster package, your colour gradient raster file only has a coordinate system of Rows x Columns. How does your polygon relate to that? How are you then going "mask" the raster? I really think you should use the raster package (or the newer, in-development "terra" package) - its what they do and will have already saved you this hassle.